# Solidus - First time installation, error when trying to run the spree:install generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, solidus

I need your help.

I've been trying to follow the instruction on this site: [Solidus First-time installation](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/blob/master/guides/getting-started/first-time-installation.md)

And I kept getting an error at this step: `bundle exec rails generate spree:install`

Error as follow:

```
    /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/deprecation/proxy_wrappers.rb:124:in `initialize': undefined method `instance' for ActiveSupport::Deprecation:Class
Did you mean?  instance_of? (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/deprecation/proxy_wrappers.rb:10:in `new'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/deprecation/proxy_wrappers.rb:10:in `new'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/load_error.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:39:in `setup'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:24:in `setup'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:33:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/filename/ecommerce/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/filename/ecommerce/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/filename/ecommerce/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/filename/ecommerce/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/filename/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Could someone enlighten me what is wrong here? And what can I do to resolve it?

Cheers!

Comment: which version of spree are you using?

Comment: you mean in my gem file? i did not put any spree gem in my gemfile as the instruction did not mention it.

Comment: @ttinggggg try `bundle update` before `bundle exec rails generate spree:install`

Comment: I did exactly same and its working fine for me. try creating saperate gemset and redo bundle install

Comment: @sovalina already did :|

Comment: @RomanchSharma what ruby and rails version are you using?

Comment: @ttinggggg what are your versions of ruby and rails in your Gemfile ?

Comment: @sovalina I'm using ruby 2.5.1 and rails 5.0.6, each time i tweak around the version, a similar but different error will pop out.

Comment: try with `gem 'solidus', '~> 2.4.2'`and `gem 'solidus_auth_devise', '~> 2.1'` (and don't forget to `bundle install` :) )

Comment: @sovalina gem 'solidus' does not work for me, so i had to do this:
gem 'solidus_core', '~> 2.4.2'
gem 'solidus_api', '~> 2.4.2'
gem 'solidus_frontend', '~> 2.4.2'
gem 'solidus_backend', '~> 2.4.2'
gem 'solidus_sample', '~> 2.4.2'
gem 'solidus_auth_devise', '2.1'
gem 'deface'

and upgrade to rails 5.1.0, but i still have errors: /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/msgpack-1.2.4/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/YickTing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/msgpack-1.2.4/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError) 

):

Comment: rails 5.1.6 and ruby 2.5.1

Comment: You can try this gem update activesupport

Comment: doesn't work :< i even reinstalled ruby

Comment: problem fixed! there was something wrong with my rails configuration. and I had to uninstall rails and install again :)